# Why is media regeneration in WordPress so slow?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I am regenerating images in my WordPress using wp-cli but it is very slow. Each image takes several (about 10-20) seconds to regenerate. I am regenerating just one size (180x125) and most of the original images are normal size - few hundred kb. Am am regenerting images using wp-cli, but I had similar result using WP admin. It is all happening all on my localhost (Apache 2, MariaDB, Ubuntu 17.10, Intel i7, 32Gb ram, nVidia 1050 Ti).

If needed, I can provide more info (phpinfo...).